# How to enforce coupling polymorphic type and enum value?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, types, polymorphism

I have a state machine with one state which dispatches some message (e.g. text) to an external receiver. Before transiting to this state (let's call it *Dispatching*) previous state needs somewhere to store that message so *Dispatching* can fetch it later. As message is created in one context and consumed in another, it will be created on the heap and *State Manager* object (which manages states, transitions and event loop) keeps a reference/pointer to it. State objects are created and destroyed as state machine transits through states. Each state inherits abstract base class `State`:

```
enum StateID
{
   STATE_A,
   STATE_B,
   ...
};

class State
{
public:
   State(StateID stateID, StateManager& sm) : 
      stateID_(stateID), sm(sm_){}
   virtual ~State(){};
   virtual StateID HandleEvent(const Event& e) = 0;
   StateID id() const {return stateID_;}
protected:   
   StateID stateID_;
   StateManager& sm_;    
};
```

In order to make passing data to the next state generic, I came up with the idea of *StateData* - a piece of information passed from one state to the next one. It is stored in dynamic memory, State Manager keeps a reference to it so each state can access it. As it is possible that different types of data will be passed to different states, *StateData* can be made abstract base class, specialized for each particular state:

```
struct StateData
{
   virtual ~StateData() = 0;
};

struct StateAData : public StateData
{
   int n_;   
   StateAData(int n) : n_(n){}
};

struct StateBData : public StateData
{
   std::string str_;   
   StateBData(const std::string& str) : str_(str){}
};

...

class StateManager
{       
   boost::scoped_ptr<State> pCurrState_;
   boost::scoped_ptr<StateData> pStateData_;
   ...
public: 
    void runEventLoop()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            ...  
            //get event from a queue    
            ...

            StateID nextStateID = pCurrState_->HandleEvent(e);

            if(nextStateID == pCurrState_->id())
                continue;               

            pCurrState_.reset(0);

            switch(nextStateID)
            {
                case STATE_A:                                           
                    pCurrState_.reset(new StateA(*this));
                    break;
                case STATE_B:                               
                    pCurrState_.reset(new StateB(*this));
                    break;
                case STATE_C:                   
                    pCurrState_.reset(new StateC(*this));                       
                    break;
                ...
            }
        }   
    }
    ...       
};

class StateA
{
public:
   StateA(StateManager& sm) : State(STATE_A, sm){}

   StateID HandleEvent(const Event& e)
   {      
      switch(e.ID)
      {
         case EVENT_1:
         {
             StateAData* pData = reinterpret_cast<StateAData*>(stateMachine_.pStateData_.get());
             // do something with data, e.g. use it for transition logic
             if(pData->n_ % 2)
             {
                 stateMachine_.pStateData_.reset(new StateBData("Hello from StateA"));
                 return STATE_B;  
             }
             else
             {
                 ...
             } 
             break; 
         }             
         ... 
      }
   }    
   ...          
}
```

There is a pitfall in following lines:

```
stateMachine_.pStateData_.reset(new StateBData("Hello from StateA"));
return STATE_B;
```

If transition logic changes so from here we need to go to `STATE_C`, developer can forget to change the type of `StateBData` to `StateCData`:

```
stateMachine_.pStateData_.reset(new StateBData("Hello from StateA"));
return STATE_C;
```

...which would lead to undesired behaviour when `StateC` tries to cast down `StateData` to `StateCData`.

**How to avoid this? How to enforce matching the type of created object and returned enum value?**

Yeah, this code stinks and this is the consequence of using two piece information and using `enum` to distinguish state types instead of types themselves. `HandleEvent` could return `StateXData` and depending on this returned type (as it carries the information about the next state) State Manager would determine (by using RTTI) the next state to transit to (`X`) but I don't like this solution.

Another idea is to create an instance of the next state and pass its data into its constructor but this approach would pollute state machine design as one state would be created before previous state is destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `enum` part of the base class or provide a pure `virtual` function in the base class to return this `enum`. This way, the state itself will advertise its type.

Comment: Did you actually mean "StateData will advertise its (matching) State type"? I can now see the solution in adding `StateID` and `id()` as members of `StateData` (just like in the case of `State`) so both State Manager and the next state will consume `StateData`: State Manager to get the `StateID` and create the proper state and then the new state to read the data.

Comment: This is the idea yes, either the `type()` method is pure virtual and defined in the derived class (to respect the pure interface), or you simply use a regular function and a regular data member passed in the constructor.